# Preload php dynamic images

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a php file that generates images (it puts an watermark on images) called image.php that receives and id http://localhost/image.php?id=1.

Does anybody know of a way to preload this images using javascript / jQuery?

I tried the normal suggestions of image preloading but hey dont seem to work. I'm thinking its because the name of the file is always the same.

**Update:**

I'm using [this](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript) approach to preload the images (a simple jquery function that creates img elements)

One caveat (probably an important one so I should have stated it up front) its that I'm using the images as a background through css.

I see that the images are fetch in Firebug. but as I try to define then as a background of a div they get fetch again. I cannot reuse the actual element but I'm under the impression that the browser caching should not fetch then again.

Thanks again for any insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be as simple as sending the proper headers with your image:

From: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#93377

```
// seconds, minutes, hours, days
$expires = 60*60*24*14;
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: maxage=".$expires);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires) . ' GMT');
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the URL of your php file as the `src` of your images? If the problem is due to the name always being the same, adding a dummy version variable will prevent caching. Simply append to the `src`

```
"&v=" + "(new Date()).getTime()"
```

Since it requires Javascript, you can only do this after the page loads. Alternatively, if the page is rendered by some backend PHP script, you can insert a random version number before serving the page.

Comment: I've updated the question. But I'm using the images with css, and I already have a differentiating variable, the images id.

Comment: He actually **wants** caching.  The problem is that caching is not happening currently.